Trouble Understanding Difference in Epsilon-Delta Arguments: Why One Works But The Other Fails (Spivak Calculus Problem 5-10c)
In the problems for the limits chapter (5) of Spivak's Calculus, we are asked to prove: $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x^3)$. The relevant to the question proof alternative is:
If we assume that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^3)$ exists, say $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^3) = m$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x| < \delta$, then $|f(x^3) - m| < \epsilon$. Then if $0 < |x| < \delta^3$, we have $0 < |\sqrt[3]{x}| < \delta$, so $|f((\sqrt[3]{x})^3) - m| < \epsilon$, or $|f(x) - m| < \epsilon$. Thus $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = m$.
I thought I understood the proof for this, but then I saw the next question: "Give an example of a case when $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x^2)$ exists, but $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not. (This is true, for example, if $f(x) = 1,\text{for }x>0; -1, \text{for } x<0$). The reason I now believe I do not understand the proof, is that I see no reason the proof cannot be repeated to show the same for $x^2$ as for $x^3$. Clearly though, from the counter-example above, the same result does not hold for $x^2$.
My question is, where in the logic of the proof Spivak gives, can the process not be followed to prove that if $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x^2) = l$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x) = l$? As in, which step fails in the method when attempting the same proof with $x^2$ instead of $x^3$?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

It's true that $(\sqrt[3]{x})^3=x$, but $\sqrt{x}$ doesn't even make sense for $x<0$, and hence you can write $(\sqrt x)^2=x$ only for $x>0$.

For each $x\in\Bbb R$, $\sqrt[3]x$ exists (and this was used in the proof). But it is not true that every real number has a square root; only non-negative real numbers have it.
